# Ubuntu 16.04 Search cannot find applications

Tags: 16.04, unity-dash

I "upgraded" to Ubuntu 16.04 and am sorry I did. Problems abound,  I will only list one here.

The Dash now cannot now find any applications. Nothing shows up in any category except for the "Dash plugins", and "Files and Folders".

I can still run applications using F2 or from the terminal or launchpad.

Any help would be appreciated. Windows is looking less bad now.

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved.  Somehow the Dash plugin for Applications got disabled during the upgrade.  Re-enabling it cured the problem.  I feel foolish that I didn't see this earlier, but I learned something.  It sure is nice to have the search feature back.